# My vassal occupies land that I want for myself

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Sometimes during the war my vassal occupies a province and doesn't give it to me (they have core in province). And because of this at the end of the war I can give this province only to them. It isn't too bad, however, sometimes I don't want to strengthen my vassal.

Is there anything I can do to take this province for myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. An AI will automatically transfer occupation to you, unless it is a province it wants. Vassals only want core provinces, Allies may want other provinces of interest as well.

So, the only way you could get the province yourself in this war would be to  let the enemy reconquer it, then occupy yourself.

The second option would be to not take it in this war and conquer it later.

You could also give the province to the vassal in the peace deal, but take it from them via the subject interaction "Seize Land" afterwards, which will create significant liberty desire though.

However, I'd strongly recommend against taking core provinces from vassals. Holding a core province of a vassal brings significant relation penalties and liberty desire by itself. Just let your vassal have the province, it is not worth the trouble. They can't be very powerful, if they are missing core provinces.

Comment: That's not true, if you have specific DLCs. See my reply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wander why no one tried to correct the accepted answer, because it's wrong. Here is the proofpic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvkcn.jpg

If you have Cossacks or Art of War DLC, you can use "Transfer occupation" button in the province interface. For subjects it has additional functionality - you can transfer occupation to and FROM your subjects.

In the provided screenshot I'm playing as Songhai and have Zazzau as my vassal. Zazzau occupies the province of Rano, and I still can transfer its occupation. back to me or to my other vassal.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this doesn't work, when the vassal wants the province, i.e. it is a core. In your example screenshot, Zazzau only has a claim on the province in question. Also, if it works even with a core province my answer is still relevant for a) people who neither have rt of war or cosscacks and b) for the notice that taking cores from vassals is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I never saw a case when this interface becomes disabled due to any reason. You don't even ask the vassal to transfer occupation - you demand it, and it happens instantly. Sorry, but I'm not ready to set up a dedicated test war to check if cores change anything

Comment: If it is a core province of the vassal, it may behave as if an ally occupies it. I never checked myself, because I see no point in taking cores from a vassal. Honestly I pretty much never use transfer occupation to give a province to me, as my vassals do that automatically anyway unless they have a claim or a core.